# temporary pointer point to a using vector address

Tags: c++, parsing, pointers, binary-tree

I have a question about parsing the string s into a binary tree.

```
struct TreeNode {
string val;         // The data in this node.
TreeNode *left;   // Pointer to the left subtree.
TreeNode *right;  // Pointer to the right subtree.
};

string s="((OR (AND pass (NOT reject)) (AND (NOT pass) reject)))";
```

I do some stroke and eliminate the "(" and ")" and keep all the separate part in vector aftersplit,
aftersplit has (bottom) OR AND pass NOT reject AND NOT pass reject (back)

```
vector<string> aftersplit;
vector<TreeNode> parsetree;
while (!aftersplit.empty())//do the parsing 
{

     TreeNode *temp=new TreeNode;

    temp->val=aftersplit.back();
    temp->left=NULL;
    temp->right=NULL;        
    aftersplit.pop_back();
    if(temp->val=="AND"||temp->val=="OR"||temp->val=="=>"||temp->val=="<=>"){
        TreeNode *leftnode = new TreeNode; 

        leftnode=&parsetree.back();
        parsetree.pop_back();
        temp->left=leftnode;
        TreeNode *rightnode = new TreeNode; 

        rightnode=&parsetree.back();
        parsetree.pop_back();
        temp->right=rightnode;
        parsetree.push_back(temp); //can not put the temp into parsetree 
    }
    else if(temp->val=="NOT")
    {
        TreeNode *leftnode = new TreeNode; 

        leftnode=&parsetree.back();
        parsetree.pop_back();
        temp->left=leftnode;
        parsetree.push_back(temp);        
    }
    else {            
        parsetree.push_back(temp);
    }
```

}

I deal with string s from right to left

however when I run "TreeNode leftnode" when operator is "OR"; the lefenode was allocated an address which is using by first "AND"'s left child "pass", that is to say, the "AND"'s point to his left children at address 0x00007fff6d8da7e0, and the new temporary leftnode's is allocating address 0x00007fff6d8da7e0 too
after that 
before that the tree is like

> ```
>     (AND)            
>        / \        
>       /   \       
>    pass  (NOT)         
>           /          
>       reject
> ```

after that leftnode is allocated the address of "pass" it will like

> ```
>                 (AND)            
>                  /    \        
>                 /      \       
>               (AND)    (NOT)         
>               /    \     /     
>              /      \   /          
>           (AND) (NOT) reject
>          /    \        
>         /      \       
>      (AND)    (NOT)
> ```

and etc, all point to itself, I know there maybe something wrong with pointer, but I can not figure out.
please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(temp.val=="AND"||temp.val=="OR"||temp.val=="=>"||temp.val=="<=>"){
    TreeNode leftnode;  //appear a bug here
    leftnode=parsetree.back();
    parsetree.pop_back();
    temp.left=&leftnode;
    TreeNode rightnode;
    rightnode=parsetree.back();
    parsetree.pop_back();
    temp.right=&rightnode;
    parsetree.push_back(temp);  
}
```

Your variables `leftnode` and `rightnode` have a limited lifespan. Since they are declared in the scope of your `if`, they will be destroyed once you step out of there. Meaning their adresses become invalid ! So, each time, the content of temp.left and temp.right is going to point to some garbage data.

This is actually why you can see that you find the same address multiple times : since the previous object has been destroyed, it is being used to store the new data that you need. But that's not exactly what you want, since you want to preserve all the objects that you've created.

The easiest way would be to dynamically create the `TreeNode`s you need (and modify the rest of your code accordingly):

```
TreeNode *leftnode = new TreeNode;
TreeNode *rightnode = new TreeNode;
```

That way, they will stay valid even after stepping out of the `if`.
You must however not forget to `delete` them afterwards.

Comment: I use the TreeNode *leftnode = new TreeNode;
TreeNode *rightnode = new TreeNode; outside the if and, still can not get what I want ,would you please write more specifically, please~~~~

Comment: This also applies to your top-most node : `TreeNode temp;`. Since it's declared inside the scope of your `while` loop, it will be destroyed once you step out of it. You should modify this one as well.

Comment: I do modify the temp as well, but still the same, maybe I do not delete the treenode, where should I delete the treenode temp, leftnode and rightnode?

Comment: Actually I've just seen your code : you did not correct the main issue ! You wrote : `TreeNode leftnode=*new TreeNode();`. You are still storing your result in a `TreeNode`, which is still going to be destroyed at the end of your `if`. You _need_ to use a pointer to `TreeNode`, a `TreeNode*`, and use the address contained within.

Comment: If you use a `TreeNode*`, your object itself will not be destroyed at the end of the scope, and its address can be used safely (and by address I mean the content of your variable. As in : `TreeNode *leftnode = new TreeNode; temp.left = leftnode;`). By keeping a `TreeNode`, you just created an extra object in the heap, but stored it on the stack as well. If you use the address of the object you have on the stack, the problem is not going to be fixed.

Comment: use TreeNode *temp = new TreeNode or use TreeNode temp=*new TreeNode()?

Comment: and if I use TreeNode *temp = new TreeNode , then parsetree.push_back(temp) will went wrong

Comment: `TreeNode *temp = new TreeNode`. Your second solution copies an object dynamically allocated on the stack, which will just lead to the same problem you had before. This applies for all the `TreeNode` you are currently using. And if that doesn't fit with the rest of your code, I'm afraid you'll have to rethink how it's done !

Comment: Reference to type 'const value_type' (aka 'const TreeNode') could not bind to an lvalue of type 'TreeNode *' in parstree.push_back(temp)